Nginx Ingress Controller on Baremetal Kubernetes Cluster Issues
so I am in the process of standing up a production ready cluster to utilize on prem resources. We have a MetalLB loadbalancer installed in the cluster with a pool of IP addresses from 10.100.7.150-10.100.7.160 to be leased out. I have installed the Nginx Ingress Controller Helm Chart and setup the service as type LoadBalancer, which assigned the IP of 10.100.7.150 to the service. From there, my understanding is that I can create ingress resources for other services and NGINX will handle the routing to the appropriate service. Currently DNS is not resolving. If I were to setup a separate service as type LoadBalancer, I am able to get to the site by IP. However, using Ingress I either get a 404 not found response from Nginx when attempting to setup ingress for ArgoCD. What I would like to accomplish is having a wildcard DNSentry "*.apps.prod.lh2" that NGINX resolves and routes to the appropriate service. I have created my own default/wildcard TLS secrets for Nginx to use, but I am still at a loss as to why DNS is not resolving. I am not super knowledgeable on how this process is suppose to work so if anyone could provide some insight I'd greatly appreciate it, see below for details
SEE LINK TO QUESTION ON STACKOVER FLOW FOR ADDITIONAL IMAGES
Cannot post images here, so question asked on stackoverflow contains images related to this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78355239/nginx-ingress-controller-on-baremetal-kubernetes-cluster-issues
REFER TO THE FOLLOWING LINK FOR THE MANIFEST BEING UTLIZED FOR MetalLB
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/metallb/metallb/v0.14.4/config/manifests/metallb-native.yaml

REFER TO THE FOLLOWING LINK FOR THE HELM CHART BEING UTILIZED FOR NGINX
https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/v3.2.1/deployments/helm-chart

NOTES:

I have a defaultTLS secret created and applied to the values.yaml for the NGINX Helm Chart, this secret contains the certificate for "apps.prod.lh2"
I have a wildcardTLS secret created and applied to the values.yaml for the NGINX Helm Chart, this secrete contains the certificate for "*.apps.prod.lh2"
Any additional ingress services I create return the following

MetalLB IPAddressPool
apiVersion: metallb.io/v1beta1
kind: IPAddressPool
metadata:
  name: primary-pool
  namespace: metallb-system
spec:
  addresses:
  - 10.100.7.150-10.100.7.160

MetalLB L2Advertisement
apiVersion: metallb.io/v1beta1
kind: L2Advertisement
metadata:
  name: primary-pool-advertisement
  namespace: metallb-system
spec:
  ipAddressPools:
  - primary-pool

NGINX INGRESS CONTROLLER SERVICE
kubectl describe svc nginx-nginx-ingress-controller --namespace ingress-nginx
Name:                     nginx-nginx-ingress-controller
Namespace:                ingress-nginx
Labels:                   app.kubernetes.io/instance=nginx
                          app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                          app.kubernetes.io/name=nginx-ingress
                          app.kubernetes.io/version=3.2.1
                          helm.sh/chart=nginx-ingress-0.18.1
Annotations:              field.cattle.io/publicEndpoints:
                        [{"addresses": 
["10.100.7.150"],"port":80,"protocol":"TCP","serviceName":"ingress-nginx:nginx-nginx- 
ingress-controller","allNodes":false},{...
                          metallb.universe.tf/ip-allocated-from-pool: primary-pool
Selector:                 
app.kubernetes.io/instance=nginx,app.kubernetes.io/name=nginx-ingress
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.43.182.167
IPs:                      10.43.182.167
LoadBalancer Ingress:     10.100.7.150
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 http  31541/TCP
Endpoints:                10.42.0.84:80
Port:                     https  443/TCP
TargetPort:               443/TCP
NodePort:                 https  31790/TCP
Endpoints:                10.42.0.84:443
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Local
HealthCheck NodePort:     32304
Events:
  Type    Reason        Age                   From             Message
  ----    ------        ----                  ----             -------
  Normal  nodeAssigned  22m (x62 over 2d11h)  metallb-speaker  announcing from node 
"vbp-k8p-03" with protocol "layer2"

ARGOCD SERVICE
kubectl describe svc argocd-server --namespace argocd
Name:              argocd-server
Namespace:         argocd
Labels:            app.kubernetes.io/component=server
                   app.kubernetes.io/name=argocd-server
                   app.kubernetes.io/part-of=argocd
                   k8slens-edit-resource-version=v1
Annotations:       field.cattle.io/publicEndpoints: null
Selector:          app.kubernetes.io/name=argocd-server
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.43.239.52
IPs:               10.43.239.52
Port:              http  80/TCP
TargetPort:        8080/TCP
Endpoints:         10.42.0.22:8080
Port:              https  443/TCP
TargetPort:        8080/TCP
Endpoints:         10.42.0.22:8080
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>

ARGOCD INGRESS
kubectl describe ingress argocd-ingress --namespace argocd
Name:             argocd-ingress
Labels:           <none>
Namespace:        argocd
Address:          10.100.7.150
Ingress Class:    nginx
Default backend:  argocd-server:80 (10.42.0.22:8080)
Rules:
  Host                  Path  Backends
  ----                  ----  --------
  argocd.apps.prod.lh2
                        /   argocd-server:80 (10.42.0.22:8080)
Annotations:            field.cattle.io/publicEndpoints:
                          [{"addresses":["10.100.7.150"],"port":80,"protocol":"HTTP","serviceName":"argocd:argocd-server","ingressName":"argocd:argocd-ingress","hos...
Events:
  Type    Reason          Age                From                      Message
  ----    ------          ----               ----                      -------
  Normal  AddedOrUpdated  18m (x3 over 19m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Configuration for argocd/argocd-ingress was added or updated

